# Ordering Points based on their distance to each other ?

Tags: c++, opencv

I have a vector of 3 Points A, B and C I want to order this vector based on the distance between those points, say the biggest distance is between B and C and than C and A  and last A and B  :

how can I do that ???

```
std::sort(vectorName.begin(), vectorName.end(), 
          [](const cv::Point2f &a, const cv::Point2f &b)
          {
              cv::Point2f diff = a-b;
             return  cv::sqrt(diff.x*diff.x + diff.y*diff.y); // I know it doesn't make a sense but how can I do this 
          });
```

Comment: In short, you can't, as this doesn't define a [strict weak order](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_ordering#Strict_weak_orderings), which is required by all the Standard Library sorting mechanisms. For a quick example, in what order should the points of an equilateral triangle be? You need to think more carefully about the order in which you want your points to end up.

Comment: you can only order points with respect to the distance to a fixed point (say the origin), not with respect to the distance to each other.

Comment: @TemplateRex sort `(0,1)` and `(1,0)` based on distance from `(0,0)`.

Comment: The Manhattan distance is good enough and much faster.

Comment: @DieterLücking "Good enough" in the sense that it fails in the same way?

Comment: @BoBTFish: Yep - the ordering will not work.

Comment: You can, however, sort the edges of the triangle by length. But having no idea of what you are trying to accomplish, I don't know if it's going to help at all.

Comment: @BoBTFish who says sort can't handle equal values?

Comment: @Engine the question is ill-posed: you cannot sort individual points based on distance between pairs of points. Sorting elements of type T uses a binary comparison predicate of signature bool cmp(T, T), that is ordered in the elements. The distance however is unordered because dist(a, b) == dist(b, a)

Comment: @TemplateRex  say I want to compare dist(a,b) dist( b,c) dist(c,a) would that solve the problem ?

Comment: @Engine yes, you need to define a sequence of *ordered* pairs, then  you can sort it. So basically you are sorting the edges, rather than points of the triangle

Comment: @TemplateRex Uhh, yes. Sorry, I'm being stupid. I was thinking of a total order. You can of course choose between `std::sort` or `std::stable_sort` depending on if you care about the relative order of values considered equal by the comparison function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the question is rephrased: Get all Manhattan distances between the points in a sorted vector:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

struct Point { int x; int y; };
struct ManhattanDistance {
    std::size_t a;
    std::size_t b;

    int value;

    ManhattanDistance(std::size_t index_a, const Point& a, std::size_t index_b, const Point& b)
    :   a(index_a), b(index_b), value(abs(b.x - a.x) + abs(b.y - a.y))
    {}

    operator int () const { return value; }
};

inline std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& stream, const ManhattanDistance& x) {
    return stream << x.a << " - " << x.b << ": " << x.value;
}

int main()
{
    typedef std::pair<std::size_t, std::size_t> Pair;
    std::vector<Point> points = { {0,0}, {2,2}, {3,3}, {4,4}, {5,5} };
    std::vector<ManhattanDistance> distances;
    distances.reserve(points.size() * (points.size() - 1) / 2);
    for(std::size_t a = 0; a < points.size() - 1; ++a) {
        for(std::size_t b = a + 1; b < points.size(); ++b) {
            distances.push_back(ManhattanDistance(a, points[a], b, points[b]));
            std::cout << "Add: " << distances.back() << std::endl;
        }
    }
    std::sort(distances.begin(), distances.end(), std::greater<ManhattanDistance>());
    for(const auto& d: distances) std::cout << "Sorted: "  << d << '\n';
    std::cout << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```