# Are there any nearest neighbor data structures using a user provided hint?

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures, computational-geometry, nearest-neighbor

I am looking for a data structure holding vectors in `R^n` which could perform nearest neighbor queries using a user provided hint as to which vector is likely to be close to the query. For example:

```
class NearestNeighborStructure;
...
NearestNeighborStructure structure;
Vector vec1 = {1,0,0};
Vector vec2 = {1,1,0};
Vector vec3 = {1,1,1};
structure.insert(vec1);
structure.insert(vec2);
structure.insert(vec3);
```

Now let us suppose that I want to find the nearest neighbor to

```
Vector query = {0,0,0};
```

and for some cryptic reason I believe that `vec2` is quite close to `query`. So I call:

```
Vector nn = structure.findNNusingHint(query, vec2);  // vec2 is a hint
assert(nn == vec1); // vec1 is the correct nearest neighbor
```

The data structure should make use of the hint I provided. It should improve upon it until it gets the true nearest neighbor.

Bonus points if the structure supports insertions and deletions.

EDIT:

I am looking for structures that can compute the nearest neighbor in sublinear time. At least in some cases. Something like [k-d trees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree) or [cover trees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cover_tree).

My problem has these characteristics:

1. Dimensionality too high for k-d trees (5 - 50 dimensions)
2. Frequent insertions and deletions
3. I always have a good guess as to which vector is near to the query

I want to use this structure in an [evolutionary algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evolutionary_algorithm) used for continuous [mathematical optimization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_optimization). The algorithm contains a large population of candidate solutions. Each solution should be aware of its surroundings in this algorithm.

New candidate solutions are created by slightly modifying existing solutions. That is the existing solution out of which the new solution is created is the hint I want to use.

Comment: You might use the Manhattan Distance. (See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18308695/ordering-points-based-on-their-distance-to-each-other/18309716#18309716)

Comment: @Dieter Please, could you expand a little? I cannot see the relationship between my question and the answer you linked. I would like to use the Manhattan metric or Euclidean or Maximum. It does not matter which.

Comment: @MartinDrozdik: it seems to me that the possibility of *hinting* is merely a *solution* you came up to speed things up. Would a data structure that performs well without hinting work for you ?

Comment: @MatthieuM. Of course it would. I will edit my question to clarify.

Comment: Can you provide us the use cases for this problem to understand better. That hint vector is really intriguing.

Comment: And what is the range of values expected for the dimension in the source vector?

Comment: @Karthikeyan I expanded my question. I aim for 5-50 dimensions.

Comment: You might want to look at finger trees, which are trees optimized for lookups around some point in the tree.  I haven't seen them in this context, but I suspect they exist

Answer (score 1):

I believe you should try and aim for an [R-Tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R-tree) or [M-Tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M-tree).

In both cases, the idea is to use a bounding volume approach. For example, if you build a binary tree, you split the space in half with a hyper-plan (represented as a Vector). The hyper-plan might not be aligned on a particular axis, and the sign of the dot-product with your vector indicates whether to continue looking left or right (when placing/deleting a vector).

For the nearest neighbor search you have to:

- locate the nearest neighbor in the same bounding volume than the node itself, this is the *candidate*.
- if this *candidate* is closer than the boundary of the volume, you are done.
- if it is not, then you need to search in the neighboring volumes that are closer than the candidate.

I realize this is very high-level... specifically, I do not know efficient partitioning or update strategies. The R-Tree article references several approaches.

Comment: The M-Tree paper looks good. As a coincidence, they make experiments with 5 - 50 dimensions. Maybe I do not need a hint at all.

Comment: I will try to implement it and report results

Comment: R-Trees don't seem to be suitable for high dimensionality.

Answer (score 0):

You could do like this:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

struct Point { int x; int y; int z; };

inline std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& stream, const Point& p) {
    return stream << p.x << ", " << p.y << ", " << p.z;
}

struct NearestNeighborStructure
{
    NearestNeighborStructure(std::size_t num_points) {
        m_points.reserve(num_points);
    }

    void insert(const Point& p) {
        m_points.push_back(p);
    }

    int manhattan_distance(const Point& a, const Point& b) const {
        using std::abs;
        return abs(b.x - a.x) + abs(b.y - a.y)  + abs(b.z - a.z);
    }

    const Point& find(const Point& query /* ignored hint*/) const {
        std::size_t result = 0;
        int distance = std::numeric_limits<int>::max();
        for(std::size_t i = 0; i < m_points.size(); ++i) {
            int d = manhattan_distance(query, m_points[i]);
            if(d < distance) {
                result = i;
                distance = d;
            }
        }
        return m_points[result];
    }

    private:
    std::vector<Point> m_points;
};

int main()
{
    Point p[3] = { {1,0,0}, {1,1,0},  {1,1,1} };
    NearestNeighborStructure structure(3);
    structure.insert(p[0]);
    structure.insert(p[1]);
    structure.insert(p[2]);

    Point query = {0,0,0};
    std::cout << "Nearest: " << structure.find(query) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

You might use a different container (eg a deque) if you do not know the amout of points you will insert.

Comment: Thank you! Perhaps I phrased my question badly. I am looking for fast data structures. Your solution works, but it performs a brute force search which is not what I am looking for. I was thinking in terms of k-d trees or cover trees.

Answer (score 0):

There is the nearest neighbor graph. You can find it by looking for the closest edge  to the point and all nearest edge, I.e triangles in a delaunay triangulation. Or you can use a spatial index, for example a space filling curve. You can download my php class hilbert curve at phpclasses.org. It uses a hilbert curve to find the hamiltonian path.

Comment: I am afraid your answer is slightly short: what kind of data structure do you recommend to represent the graph ? KD-Tree ? Quadtree ? Octree ? None seem suitable here because of the high number of dimensions.

Comment: this should be a comment, not an answer

Comment: Why the enigmatic description of where the code is, instead of just providing a straightforward link?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider ball tree: http://citeseer.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download;jsessionid=54F6006443B8E4623DF398158E3284FF?doi=10.1.1.91.8209&rep=rep1&type=pdf