# Sorting a C++ vector based on an adjacency matrix

Tags: c++, matrix, mesh, adjacency-matrix

I have a vector **e** whose elements are indices to edges in a 2D (surface) mesh. For whatever reason, I would like to reorder this vector, so that each edge is surrounded by edges that are closest to it (basically, similar to what the asker is trying to achieve in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18308695/ordering-points-based-on-their-distance-to-each-other)).

I don't need it to be an exact or perfect solution (there probably isn't one), but I'd like to get as close as possible.

Here are the steps I have taken:

1. Create an adjacency matrix **B** for the mesh edges,
2. Use an algorithm such as [RCM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cuthill%E2%80%93McKee_algorithm) to get a reordering of the adjacency matrix to reduce its bandwidth (I'm using Petsc's MatGetOrdering to do this),
3. Apply the new ordering to get a new, reshuffled adjacency matrix, **B2**.

At this point, I would like to reorder the original vector **e** of mesh edges, to get a new vector **e2** whose adjacency matrix is now **B2**.

- Is this possible? i.e. is there enough information above to achieve this?
- Is this a good approach to do what I'm trying to achieve?

  - If not, what would be the most sensible and robust approach? (e.g. I was also playing around with trying to do this based on physical distances rather than edge connectivity, but I'm not sure which approach is more realistic / sensible / robust),
  - If yes, how do I accomplish the last step of reordering the edge vector based on the new adjacency matrix?

I'm fairly new to Stack Exchange so please let me know if I should be asking this on another sub-community. I am also fairly new to graph theory, so I may be missing something obvious.

Thanks!

Comment: Keeping track of what the reordering algorithm does seems easier than reconstructing what it did.  Either add a tag to the elements (saying what index it refers to in your vector) or actually repeat the operations (so they also reorder your vector) depending on how your algorithm is wrapped.

Comment: Stack exchange sites for: computer graphics, computer science, and math are all good places to ask IMO.

Comment: How about doing a BFS and storing the edges in the order rhey have been discovered?

Comment: As for the question: how about doing [PCA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_component_analysis) and sorting edges along the first principal component? Could be rather easy and hopefully good enough.

Comment: Thanks for all the suggestions!